# gestureRecognizer:shouldReceiveTouch: implementation failing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I'm trying to ignore my gestureRecognizer if the view touched is of certain classes (namely `UIButton` and `UIBarButtonItem`) using this:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {

  NSLog(@"%@", touch.view);

  if ([touch.view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]){
    return NO;
  } else if ([touch.view isKindOfClass:[UIBarButtonItem class]]){
    return NO;
  }
  return YES; // handle the touch
}
```

That works great for `UIButton`. It doesn't work for `UIBarButtonItem`. My NSLog results when the `UIBarButtonItem` is touched are:

```
<UIToolbarTextButton: 0x7b8f500; frame = (4 0; 60 40); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7b8f900>> 2012-06-26 12:09:48.021
```

I have tried changed the `[UIBarButtonItem class]` to `[UIToolBarTextButton class]`, but as this is an undocumented class, I cannot do it. Any other way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try `UIBarItem`?

Comment: I just did, that doesn't appear to work either.

Comment: Try ignoring the whole bar!!!

Answer (score 0):

If your UIBarButtonItem is in a UINavigationBar, then you would need to subclass UINavigationBar and implement another

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {
```

in order to catch the gesture for the UIBarButtonItem. There may be other ways of achieving this.